# save variables in file on sdcard (ANDROID)

Tags: android

im writing an app and now i have two variables that i want to save to a file on sdcard..
i searched everywhere and i couldn't find a complete code!

this is the part of my code that i want to export the variables from :

```
  String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "From: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();
```

now i want to save these two strings to a file (senderNum and message)

Answer (score 0):

Don't need use a file, just [preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) or [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName or PrefsName",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
prefEditor.putInt("senderNum", senderNum);
prefEditor.putString("message", message);
prefEditor.commit();
```

Comment: or you will have many files? Same code, but in line SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(**"UniqueID"**,MODE_PRIVATE); Where for example UniqueID is hash from name, surname, sender number or all together.

Comment: and just a good practice using java Serializable, look this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String toWriteData = "senderNum = " + senderNum + " message = " + message;

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "storeFile.txt");

    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

        fos.write(toWriteData.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Add appropriate names while writing so that they can be used to retrieve data later on.

Comment: thank you it ws very usefull, though they are backtoBackand cant be recognized , is there any way that the be seperated and also when tey change, the new value come the line after not be overwrited??

Comment: You can take them in a single `String` like `String toWriteData = "senderNum = "+senderNum +" message = "+message;` and then write that `toWriteData` to the file. When next time you want to add new values check if `storeFile.txt` exists then use    `FileWriter writer=  new FileWriter(file);
     
     writer.append(toWriteData)`. Let me know if this was useful?

Comment: i did the first part and it works great <3 , i really thank you, but i didnt get the second part, can you make it more clear? or change it in the main code? thank you a lot .

Comment: by values i meant the same values of senderNum and Message but when they change, for example first it writes the first line and its okay, but when another message comes , they are changed and when they are wirtten in file again, they delete the first line and so..